# Super High Ping Rates to Router (That randomly happen)

Tags: windows-7, router, ping

For the last 2 to 3 weeks I am getting extremely high ping rates to my router and it randomly seems to happen.

I have recently bought [freephoneline.ca](http://www.freephoneline.ca/) which is a voip solution that can be hooked up to a regular phone by buying an ata adapter(I have Grandstream HT-286 ATA).

Since the day I plugged in the ATA adapter to my [dlink wireless N dir 655 router](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/d-link-xtreme-wireless-n-router-dir-655/10082039.aspx?path=b2c816647b95db1b73f3935150cf98fden02) I been having high ping rates when trying to ping the router(can go from 1ms to 3000+ms or just timeout).

The pings are very random and the thing is I can go days with a normal ping rate and download speed(6+ megabits) to high pint rates and waiting 5mins for a webpage to load up.

I have another pc and another laptop. They do not experience this high ping rate or anything in that nature. The pc has the same wireless card as the computer that is having problem.

The other computer is in the same room as the router but the computer having problems is like 20 feet away from that computer. So it is not like these computers are miles apart

I not sure how I can test what is going on and why I am getting this. I know when I disconnect the adapter and unplug the router it seems to be find again but like I said I can go days with the ATA adpater plugged in and getting good ping rates with the 6+ megabit downloads.

So it just so random and I have no clue how to figure out why only this one computer has this problem and why it just randomly happens.

I have usually 4 to 5 bars in the windows 7 network area so that seems fine.

Any one have any ideas on how I can figure out what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: A good way to test this would be taking the wireless adapter from the computer nearest the router (the working one) and trying it in the one you are having problems with. If no other wireless devices are experiencing problems, it is more likely you have a bad adapter than your VoIP solution is randomly affecting only one computer.

Comment: Well I don't think that is the problem and I rather not start ripping out the computers(unless I have no other better tests to do first). I mean the internet was literally working good till I plugged in the ata adapter and I instantly got the problem.

Comment: So unplug the ATA adapter and see if the problem goes away? I think it is more likely to be a computer-related issue than device related, due to it only affecting one computer though.

Comment: Yes already did that and like I said once I unplug it I don't seem to have that problem anymore(I had the same setup for over 4 months now and it just happened to start the same time I installed this ata adapter).

Comment: How long did you test it for when the ATA adapter was unplugged? If it can work for days when it is connected, does it work for a longer period of time when the adapter is not connected?

Comment: I probably had it at least off for 30mins and just before I had it unplugged I was having the issue. I unplugged reset the router and it worked. I have not tried longer then that. I will see if I can try that.

Comment: If it works longer when it is unplugged than it does when it is plugged in, it may very well be the ATA adapter/VoIP package, but as I said, it does seem quite unlikely it would only affect one machine. If you can try it, then that's probably where I would head next.